# How can you inspect the Dialog Stack on Botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm implementing a feedback dialog, and want to drop into the dialog from anywhere using an `IScorable` and key off the word "feedback" and push my `FeedbackDialog` onto the stack.

I don't want this behavior while collecting feedback from the user. Is there a way to determine if my `FeedbackDialog` is already on the stack? So I don't accidentally double push it?

Answer (score 4):

You can resolve the stack like the following. First, register the necessary modules:

```
private void RegisterTypes()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new DialogModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new DialogModule_MakeRoot());
    // necessary configurations
    // ...
}
```

After that, resolve the stack:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
}
```

in `stack.Frames` you can find the list of the dialogs in order of them in the stack dialog(`stack.Frames[0]` is on the top of the stack). You can find the name of the dialog using `Target` property of a `Frame`, i.e., `stack.Frames[0].Target`. Therefore, you can find the `FeedbackDialog` in the stack if it exists using the following code:

```
stack.Frames.Any(x=> x.Target.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType.Name == "FeedbackDialog")
```

Comment: Where should I post this code? I added the type registrations in the `WebApiConfig` and the stack resolver in the `MessagesController` but Autofac throws errors and my bot becomes unresponsive.